# Why does an underscore get matched like a wildcard in python 3 re library

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to make the following fail unless
the reg.match exactly contains Path_WhateverAfterTheUnderscore. It doesn't seem to be strictly trying to match an underscore with the given string. I have also tried escaping the underscore in the re.compile string pattern but that didnt work either. The test code I am trying to get to work is:

```
import re
reg = re.compile('Path_*')
# This should return None unless it has 'Path_' in it which it doesnt.
# Instead this successfully returns a match of Path
print(reg.match("PathName"))
p = reg.match("PathName")
print(p.group())
```

This passes when I want it to fail because PathName has no underscore in it following Path

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `*` itself to be a wildcard, like how it works in globs, or common search engines. In regex `*` is a quantifier that gets applied to the preceding character or group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk (`*`) in regex means "0 or more of the previous character". The pattern `Path_*` matched `PathName` because it has 0 underscores after "Path".

Perhaps what you are looking for is the expression:

```regex
Path_.*
```

Meaning: the exact string `Path_`, followed by any character (`.`) any number of times.

This will match: `Path_`, `Path_A`, `Path_Name`, but not `Path`, `PathName`, `Paths`.

For more information see [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html).

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. Thank you!